# How to stop this jquery animate from opening if already open?

Tags: php, jquery

I have 7 items in a menu that animates downwards with jquery using mouseover. My question is, how can I stop the animate if dropdown menu already is open?:

```
jQuery('.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li:nth-child(1)>a').mouseover(function(){
jQuery('.navbar>li:nth-child(1)>.dropdown-menu-custom').animate({height: "toggle"}, 500, function(){});
```

I know I need an if statement, but not sure what to put in it?
Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 0):

just add a class **.active** to each item when its open and remove is if its not, then when the **mouseover()** event is triggered you can just check if that is 'active' or not if true then stop the script else go animate.

Hope this helps.